# In .NET, what are the downsides if any of using 'using'-blocks?

Tags: .net, vb.net, using

Are there any downsides to using `Using`? I understand that outside of a `Using` block I'm not going to be able to use that resource but are there circumstances where I should leave it to the garbage collector?

Here is some example code with nested `using`s.

```
Dim ftpReq As FtpWebRequest = Nothing

subSetupFtp(ftpReq, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory) 'Setup FTP

    Dim lstFileNames As New List(Of String)

    'Get FTP response
    Using webRes As WebResponse = ftpReq.GetResponse()
    'read filenames into list to return
        Using ftpStream As New StreamReader(webRes.GetResponseStream())
            Do While ftpStream.Peek <> -1
                lstFileNames.Add(ftpStream.ReadLine)
            Loop
            lstFileNames.Sort() 'alphabetically sorts the list(a-z) ie. The files are now in date order

            'Tidy up
            ftpStream.Close()
            webRes.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Be careful asking "should I do this?" questions - they might be perceived as not constructive. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object has [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) implemented with then, it is always better to use it with `Using`, which internally works as a try / finally block. This will ensure its disposal even if any exception occurs.

> circumstances where i should leave it to the garbage collector?

[IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.
>   The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a
>   managed object when that object is no longer used. **However, it is
>   not possible to predict when garbage collection will occur**.
>   Furthermore, the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged
>   resources such as window handles, or open files and streams.

Comment: The exception would be if you were going to return the object to your caller.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no any downside, at least known to me.

Everytime you deal with Disposable object that has local scope of life, use `using`.

In this way you will benefit, that even in case of the exception inside the `using` scope, on `Disposable` object `Dispose(..)` will be called by the way, as `using` is nothing else, then:

```
try {

}
finally {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If an object implements `IDisposable` then there is no harm using a `using` block.

You need to be careful of scope though. If you are adding an object to a list within a using block which you intend to use later on then you will end up with an object ref error if you try and access that object.